# module pcntl already loaded in unknown on line 0

Tags: apache, ubuntu, pcntl

After installation *pcntl* encounters an error while running tests (`make test`)

> Module 'pcntl' already loaded in unknown on line 0

Thus on many forums the same - comment out in the `*.ini` files row

> Disable_functions =
>   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl

I found it in the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, commented out, restart *apache2*, did not help. Restarting the server does not help.

How do I fix this error?

*ubuntu 14.04*
*apache 2.4.7*
*php5 5.5.9*

Comment: Is not linked statically? You can verify in the output of phpinfo();

Comment: in phpinfo (); no information on pcntl 0_o

Comment: It is strange because the related php's source package's debian rules compiles php with --enable-pcntl. http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/php5